# how to group by multiple value as one in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I need help to group by `id` and `code_doc`, but for code 10 and 11 combine as one group.

Thanks in advance

MYSQL Structure:

```
 ID | CODE_DOC| 
---------------
 2  |   10   |  
 2  |   11   |  
 2  |   21   |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression to convert 11 to 10 (or visa-versa) so they'll end up in the same group:

```sql
SELECT   id, CASE code_doc WHEN 11 THEN 10 ELSE code_doc END as code_doc
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY id, CASE code_doc WHEN 11 THEN 10 ELSE code_doc END
```

Comment: but when i add select sum amout value show 0 not real sum amount value , any advice ?

Comment: @JeheAcoroxz sum of what? please share you query.

Comment: SELECT a.id,
CASE a.code_doc WHEN 10 THEN 11 ELSE a.code_doc END as kod,SUM(a.amaun) amt

FROM mytable a
WHERE a.id= '4'
group by a.id,CASE a.code_doc WHEN 10 THEN 11 ELSE a.code_doc END

Comment: @JeheAcoroxz See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=10f12541b4a9c4bdf32ae17764703150)